# How to configure a private DNS server on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, cloudflare

Android supports Cloudfare's private DNS `1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com`.
But on Windows 10 I couldn't find a way to set up anything other than IPv4 and IPv6 DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not yet have built-in support for DNS over TLS, and only the very latest [Insider build 19628](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/windows-insiders-can-now-test-dns-over-https/ba-p/1381282) has built-in support for DNS over HTTPS.

In the mean time, you can install a proxy such as Stubby or Dnscrypt which presents a "normal" DNS server on localhost, then relays them over either DoH or DoT.